# Why aren't specific packages showing up?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hey I'm kinda new to linux and ubuntu so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I can't seem to install some packages with apt-get. They are just non existent. For example, I'm trying to install [php5-imap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/php5-imap), and it's obviously in the repository, but when I apt-get it it can't find that package. My sources.list is as follows:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ubuntu.secs.oakland.edu dapper main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.secs.oakland.edu dapper-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

According to the website, it exists. Why can't I get this package?

Comment: no such thing as stupid questions*


*just stupid people! :-) this is a good question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to insult by starting with the ultra-basics, but have you run "`apt-get update`"?

If so, please paste the output of "`apt-cache search php5-imap`" and "`sudo apt-get install php5-imap`"

Comment: I actually fixed my problem. I got rid of the repositories I had and replaces them with the official us.archive.ubuntu.com ones. I did apt-update and it worked. No idea what the issue was.